# creating a server that listens at two different ports

Tags: java, sockets

I have an app in java that is nothing but a remote server.The remote server I wanna design to accept two kinds of client:

1.Some that connect at 127.0.0.1 at the port 6000

2.The second type of client that connects at 127.0.0.1 at the port 6500

How do I do that???

I've tried the following:

```
public class Start {

    Socket socket=null;
    private String  serverIpAddress="127.0.0.1";
    static Thread cThread;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ThreadPooledServer server = new ThreadPooledServer(6000);
        new Thread(server).start();




        cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
        cThread.start();

    }
```

Where `ThreadPooledServer` and `ClientThread` are two different classes.

When I wanna start the second thread ....and that means this line:

`cThread.start();`  ....java tells me that "No enclosing instance of Start type is accessible!!!"

According to me it means that I cannot start two different threads in the same main.....Well,if I can't do it this way...what is the proper way to do it?....to start two threads

1.That listen on the local machine to port 6000

2.Second that listen on the local machine at port 6500???

UPDATE: I wanna create a server that can listen on multiple ports and when I get a new connection, I want to be able to tell which port that connection used!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are setting them both to the same port in your example, that fails as designed: you can't have two apps listening at the same host:port combination. What happens in your ClientThread class?

Comment: No no.....on the same host I have two threads :one listening to port 6000 and one listening to another port let say 61000.....How do I do that cause the above code definitly won't work!!!!!?

Comment: In my ClientThread class I'm launching the thread to listen to the second thread.....But u haven't read carefully....THE ABOVE CODE IS NOT WORKING IS JUST A STUPID EXAMPLE!!!!My question is how I do this thing properly?????

Comment: @mariana: Please calm down, stop shouting and tell us what *actually* happens there, as your code is (according to you) not entirely relevant to the question? Can you show us the relevant part of the code then? Java doesn't let you do *what*? Is there a compile error? A runtime exception? What does it say?

Comment: Now you're just repeating things. Calm down and help us and yourself clarify the problem!

Comment: ok....what don't u understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen on multiple ports in an efficiant way (=SingleThreaded) it may be a good idea to have a look at java.nio.SocketChannel and Selector, but I assume this is overkill for a low load scenario.

Regarding the "No enclosing instance of type Start is accessible.":

Either create the treads in the constructor and create a new object of your class or declare the inner class static (if it does not need access to outer classes members)